# How to convert MathML to Text(Python)

Tags: python, xml, selenium, selenium-webdriver, mathml

I'm working on a project where the program should simplify a term.
First, this should be read from the website, then calculated and then return the correct solution.
However, I have the problem that the term is displayed in MathML and therefore cannot be easily scraped with Python selenium.
Is it possible to convert the term to a simple string. Best with a python library or something similar?

This is the website to take the term from:
https://mathebattle.de/edu_randomtasks/training_show/480

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please show us what the "simple string" should look like. There are two fractions in the mathematical expression. How should they be represented?